# How to get a set of an instance variable using Stream

Tags: java, java-stream

I have a class called Change.  This class has two String variables called format and description, with normal getters and setters.

If I have a `ArrayList<Change>` changes how do I get a Set of all the different Formats using Java Streams?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You use `Stream#map` method in order to get a `Stream` of strings (based on the "method" you passed as argument), and then you `collect` it using `Stream#collect` method.

For example:

```
public class Change {
    private String format;
    private String description;

    public Change(String format, String description) {
        this.format = format;
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public String getFormat() {
        return format;
    }

    public void setFormat(String format) {
        this.format = format;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Change> list = new ArrayList<>();
        list.add(new Change("format1", "descr1"));
        list.add(new Change("formatelse", "descrelse"));

        Set<String> formats = list.stream().map(Change::getFormat).collect(Collectors.toSet());
    }
}
```